# Semtech Lora Packet forwarder with Dragino Shield: How to configure the pins on packer forwarder?

Tags: lora, lorawan

As far I have seen that these links:

- [USE LORA SHIELD AND RPI TO BUILD A LORAWAN GATEWAY](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Lora-Shield-and-RPi-to-Build-a-LoRaWAN-Gateway/)
- [LoRaWAN](https://www.mobilefish.com/developer/lorawan/lorawan_quickguide_build_lora_gateway.html)

But they use an obsolete packer forwarder: https://github.com/tftelkamp/single_chan_pkt_fwd as a result I cannot see traffic through ttn monitor:

[image]

So I need to use the Semtech's one: https://github.com/Lora-net/packet_forwarder

But the problem is whether the semtech's one packer forwarder will be compatible with the Dragino shield connected to rpi zero w as [wiring diagram](https://www.mobilefish.com/images/developer/raspberry_pi3_model_b_dragino_shield_wiring.jpg) shows

So I have the burning question:
How I will configure the pinout in Semtech's packet forwarder in order for it to locate the dragino shield?

In the `single_chan_pkt_fwd` has a section where I can indicate where each pin will do a job for example which pin will read the status from `DI0` pin. But on Semtech's one I cannot locate this type of configuration.

Comment: You need to go through the code and find where it interfaces with the radio itself or abstracts that out to some other software component that must be there to help it.  It's quite possible it's not really intended for this usage at all - it may instead assume an interface like that of a gateway-class radio rather than a cheap node radio, since the simultaneous support for multiple frequencies and spreading factors offered by a gateway-class radio is what is normally required to do this job in a meaningful, real-world-useful sort of way.